# while creating JAR from eclipse?How to set class path in manifest file ,

Tags: java, jar, command, manifest

I am done trying with all the solutions provided. Please help with this:

I am trying to create an executable jar for my project with manifest file. But I keep on get the error no class found.

My manifest file looks like below and it is in project level. I create a jar from eclipse through export.

`Manifest-Version: 1.0`

`Main-Class: com.tn.gov.runParser.RunParser`

`Class-Path: commons-logging-1.1.1.jar s.jar t.jar 3.jar j.jar o.jar s.jar util.jar xml.jar xml.jar`

Answer (score 0):

When you export your project into a JAR, on the prefrences/config page, under "Launch configuration" would be all the possible Classes to put in `Main-Class:` Also, you could edit `MANIFEST.MF` on the `Main-Class:` line manually.